# Magento 2.3.5 Categories Automatically Unassigned/Removed From The Product

Tags: category, category-products, category-tree, magento2.3.5

After upgrading to the latest Magento 2.3.5,

Assigned categories have automatically removed from the product after sometime add/edit products.

Example:
I have assigned the following categories in one product.

[image]

After a few minutes, categories auto removed from assigned products.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After saving, you might wanna check on db itself and see if the changes are reflected or not. If yes, it may just be matter of cleaning cache and reindexing.

Comment: I have checked the database table 'catalog_category_product' with an example and after 2 minutes, 4 categories have removed automatically from the database. Strange!

Comment: I have added one product with 12 categories: https://prnt.sc/tlmnxe

I have refreshed after 2 minutes and 4 categories have removed automatically from the database.
https://prnt.sc/tlmodp

Comment: I just tried updating categories in my dev env with 2.3.5-p1. it works fine and within debug log I could trace some entries `catalog/product/save/`

Comment: It's possible that your tables might be corrupted or something or it just may be any external service which resets the stock, I may not be able to comment more without knowing all the circumstances. I would recommend [watching for/setup db logs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/log/log-db.html) to find out more about this issue.